# Updating Shopware version 4.3.0 to 5.1.6

Tags: php, shopware

While upgrading shopware version 4.3.0 to 5.1.6 get below error after data migration step-4

Slim Application Error

The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: Zend_Json_Exception

Message: Decoding failed: Syntax error

File: ../engine/Library/Zend/Json.php
Line: 93

Answer (score 0):

Do you use php5.6?
This might be caused by a wrong php-version. Since shopware 4 doesn't support anything newer than shopware 5.6, you need 5.6 running to update the system.

Comment: I have tried upgrade shopware on both php version 5.6 and 7.1 but same error occurred

Comment: Ok, I checked the history of php (release date of 5.6 is 08/2014) and shopware (release date of 4.3.0 is 07/2014), so it might be possible that this won't work even with php5.6. I recommend trying php5.5